# Flash of white when changing orientation on iOS Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome, safari, media-queries

What causes the flash of white to the right of a responsive design when changing orientation from portrait to landscape on the iPhone with iOS 6?

**Try it on Safari for iOS 6:**

1. Websites like this don't do it: http://html5boilerplate.com
2. But this one does: http://www.initializr.com

Something to do with re-processing (CPU lag) to fit a wider screen?

It doesn't happen in Chrome for iOS6...

---

For example, I just removed all `img` from my own testing site and set the background of `<body>`, `<html>` etc. to non-white, but it still happens. This seems to happen with a lot of different websites out there, but others are completely immune to it...

Could it be a problem with someone on the website, or an iOS Safari bug?

Comment: Webkit flash. Chrome has issues with it as well.

Comment: Interesting, but in this case: Chrome works

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of the elements in the header of http://www.initializr.com/ which (dis)appear when changing orientation. It forces the header to resize and the elements below are pushed down. This causes a repaint of the DOM, that causes the short white flash on iOs.

Comment: The header doesn't disappear on the iPhone 4

Comment: With the "(dis)appearing elements" i meant the `<div id="follow-container">`. But on the iPhone 4 that div is never shown at all. But what does happen is, the `<h2>` breaks into 2 lines. This has the same effect: the header resizes, the elements below it are pushed down, DOM gets repainted